# Integers in list changing for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I'm trying to learn python and doing silly little exercises but they help immensly. The current exercise has me write a program that makes a dictionary with the days of the week with the corresponding number as the key:

1:Monday
2:Tuesday
...

This is what I have so far:

```
dayNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
dayName = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]  
week = {}  
for n in dayNumber:  
    week[dayNumber[n]] = dayName[n]
```

However when I run the program the first entry in the list is 2:Tuesday. I can make it work by changing:

```
dayNumber = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
for n in dayNumber:  
    week[dayNumber[n]+1] = dayName[n]
```

but this doesn't seem like the right way to handle this. What is going on...

Thanks for the help

Comment: Bear in mind that lists in Python start at zero - so dayname[1] is 'Tuesday' not monday.  in your new code snippet you don't need to daynumber[n] - you already have the number from the list in your n variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lists in Python start at zero - so `dayname[1]` is 'Tuesday' not `Monday`

In both of your code snippets you don't need to `daynumber[n]` - you already have the number from the list in your n variable. A for loop gives you the value from your list - not the index into your list.

This should work :

```
dayNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
dayName = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]  
week = {}  
for n in dayNumber:  
    week[n] = dayName[n-1]
```

or even better

```
dayNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
dayName = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] 
week = dict(zip(dayNumber, dayName))
```

For large lists (1000 entries) - zip seems to almost twice as fast as the naive for loop version - probably because zip is written in C.

Comment: I guess my confusion is that i thought the for loop would have started at 0 for both lists. Daynumber [0] and dayname [0] would have been the first entries in the dictionary

Comment: they start on the zeroth entry - regardless of the value of the entry. as you say your second version does work - but only because you use your value from the list to index back into the list - which is pointless in this case. The right way to do what you are trying to do is by using `zip` - i.e. my second solution.

Comment: Can you accept this please - if it is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Python list are 0-based index i.e first element in list is present at "0" position,list[0]

> you could replace `week[dayNumber[n]] = dayName[n]` with `week[n] = dayName[n-1]`

```
dayNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
dayName = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday"]  
week = {}  
for n in dayNumber:  
    week[n] = dayName[n-1]
```

Comment: `dayNumber[1]` is '2' - so it will be one out the other way - not what you intended i think.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 : i have edit the response. thanks for pointing out the mistake